# Why is my If function not working Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a function that changes the place of text.It is conditional on the contents of the html element. It's supposed to check if the element contains text. If it does, it will change the contents of the second element. If it doesn't, I want it to stop the function. Any help?

```js
function transferText() {
  if (document.getElementById('aaa') !== '') {
    document.getElementById('bbb').innerHTML = document.getElementById('aaa').innerHTML;
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<p id="aaa"></p>
<button onclick="transferText()"> click me</button>
<p id="bbb">bbb</p>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it seems to work perfectly fine, you have nothing inside `<p id="aaa"></p>` and that is why it empties `<p id="bbb">bbb</p>`

Comment: An HTMLElement will never be equal to an empty string…!?

Comment: ^  `document.getElementById('aaa') !== ''` ... this will always be true.

Comment: `console.log(document.getElementById('aaa'), ' !== "" ')`

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out, you are comparing an HTMLElement to an empty string.
The following works:

```js
function transferText() {
  if (document.getElementById('aaa').innerHTML !== '') {
    document.getElementById('bbb').innerHTML = document.getElementById('aaa').innerHTML;
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<p id="aaa">eeee</p>
<button onclick="transferText()"> click me</button>
<p id="bbb">bbb</p>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is working, `document.getElementById('aaa')` is checking the element exists, which will always be true. This then sets the value of `'bbb'` to the value of `'aaa'`, which in your example, is `''`.